# Recommendations for Physics sounds

Tags: sfx, sound-libraries

I'm looking for some physics sound libraries, one or many (depends upon diversity). I haven't been in the market for sound libraries in a long time, and I really need to update. I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on sound libraries of physics sounds. I'm particularly interested in impact sounds and continuous contacts (rolling, sliding etc.) between objects of different sizes/materials. Not particularly interested in breaking, fracturing, aggregate materials (e.g. footsteps on gravel).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is bias due to recommending a particular brand/company that I have used in the past.

I would suggest a company called "Hiss and Roar" the sound designer Tim Prebble has incredible set of sound design libraries, recordings of numerous physical interactions.

Here are some titles of foley packs that may aid you: Mechanical, friction, chains, entropy and springs.

Here is his website:

http://hissandaroar.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could try Video Copilot's "Motion Pulse" soundpack, an, In my honest opinion a great, high fidelity (24-bit wav) pack with a shit ton of sounds, ranging from impacts to organic life, lots of debris and falling stuff sounds (wood, metal etc). also contains slices, doppler effects, drones, organics, mechanics (big, small, micro), drops (both objects and (sub)bass). hits, punches, up-rises and down-risers, glitches, signals, and much more.

https://www.videocopilot.net/products/motionpulse/